# Launching Word-based Hyperlinks in Incognito mode

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink, private-browsing

I have a **Word document with hyperlinks** that currently open fine in Google Chrome... however, is there anyway to format these hyperlinks (or any other method) so the **links open** automatically in **Incognito mode**?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Word goes to your default browser. Unless that browser is set to, by default, open new pages in incognito/private windows, I do not expect any other application to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome extensions with the permission can use the chrome.windows.create method:tabs

```
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

However, to access it, you'll either need to write your own extension or find an existing one which provides a suitable hook.